# How should I arrange my projects/classes in .NET to avoid circular dependecies

Tags: c#, user-interface, oop, visualization, circular-dependency

My program is attempting to draw [grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) in C# & WPF. I have:

1 DataStructure project which describes a tree structure of how it should be visualised. Each node in the tree relates to a symbol in the grammar. Nodes at the top define the rule for that nonterminal symbol.

1 Drawer project which describes the user controls in WPF.

I need to reference drawer in my datastructure as when i traverse the tree, I call *DataStructure.draw();* on each node. I also need to reference the datastructure in my drawer project so I can respond to a user clicking on my GUI, it will update the data structure.

This creates a circular depedency, I have tried to use a controller class but I have no idea :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the Visitor pattern, described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

This will allow your datastructure project to accept a visitor of any type, including a drawer, but the implementatin of the actual visitor (in your case the drawing logic) to live separately with no dependency in the way you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to reference drawer in my
>   datastructure as when i traverse the
>   tree, I call DataStructure.draw();

Quick fix: traverse and call `HelperObject.Draw(DataStructure);`

Your DataStructure shouldn't know how to Draw itself, pretend it has to be re-used in a WinForms or other platform. HelperObject could be part of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Extract common functionality out of your objects until a third layer of abstraction. You may also want to look at [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) where your grammer would be the Model, your drawer would be the View, and you still need the controller.